# How can I make span’s text into hyperlink and it should execute a function

Tags: jquery

I have a span (id=”OverdueReportsCount”). How can I make span’s text into hyperlink and it should execute a function (CountReports)?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/billymoon/GV87J/

```
$('#OverdueReportsCount')
    .wrapInner(
        $('<a />')
            .attr({href:'#'})
            .click(CountReports)
    );
```